# CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: python, html, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSRF Protection in Django 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074844/csrf-protection-in-django-1-4)

I am trying to make a simple system for ticket reservation for rockets using Django. However, every time I try to reserve a ticket, I get the Forbidden 403 error: `CSRF token missing or incorrect`.

Here is my code:

#### models.py:

```
class Tickets(models.Model):
    rocket_line = models.ForeignKey('Rockets')
    date = models.DateField()
    number_of_seats = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ordered_on = models.DateTimeField()
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

#### views.py:

```
def order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        order = Tickets(
            rocket_line = Rockets.objects.get(id=request.POST['rocket_line']),
            date=request.POST['date'],
            number_of_seats=request.POST['number_of_seats'],
            email=request.POST['email'],
            ordered_on=datetime.now(),
            total_price=(float(number_of_seats) * float(Rockets.objects.get(id=request.POST['rocket_line']).rprice))
        )
        order.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/menu/')
    else:
        all_rockets = Rockets.objects.all().order_by('rtime')
        return render_to_response('order.html', { 'all_rockets': all_rockets},  RequestContext(request))
```

#### order.html:

```
<h1>You can order a ticket here:</h1>

        <form action="/order/" method="post">       
        <p>             
        <label>Rocket_line</label>
        <select name="rocket_line">
            {% for rocket in all_rockets %}
                <option value="{{ rocket.id }}">{{ rocket }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <label>Date</label>
        <input name="date" value="YYYY-MM-DD" type="text" size="10" />
        <label>Number of seats</label>
        <input name="number_of_seats" value="" type="text" size="10" />
        <label>E-mail</label>
        <input name="email" value="@" type="text" size="50" />
        <br /><br />
        <input class="button" value="Order" type="submit" />        
        </p>        
        </form>             
    <br />
```

Could you help me to resolve, where the problem might be?

Comment: add {% csrf_token %} inside your <form></form> tags

Comment: are you really selling rocket seats? how much for one btw?

Comment: No, it is just a school project and I wanted to be original, so I am making an Earth-Mars trasportation system by some rockets... trains and planes are just too mainstream :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

taken from the almighty django's [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it):

Step 1:

> Add the middleware 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' to your list of middleware classes, MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. (It should come before any view middleware that assume that CSRF attacks have been dealt with.)

Step 2:

```
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

that {% csrf_token %} is all you need to add to your template.

there's other solutions around (decorators or ajax based) but this one is the fastest and most used (i think, at least... it requires no hassle whatsoever to be implemented)

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not await such a quick response, that would fully solve my problem. Is there a way to give you some credit for that, or is it given by the system automatically?

Comment: You accepted the answer, that's enough :) And you solved your problem, that's even better :) Don't worry about credit or similar here, but thanks anyway! Just a quickie: before even googling, dig deep into the docs. There's almost everything there!